# python3 torch waning removal

Tags: python, pytorch, torch

I have a python script the uses torch and easyocr.
When I run it I get in the terminal my output but also I see two warnings:

```
CUDA not available - defaulting to CPU. Note: This module is much faster with a GPU.
[W NNPACK.cpp:79] Could not initialize NNPACK! Reason: Unsupported hardware.
```

Is there a way to add something in my python code to suppress those two warnings?
Thanks.

I tried this below but it did not work:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import cv2
import numpy as np
import easyocr
import sys
import requests
import os

os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]=""
```

Thanks.

Comment: `python3 -W ignore file.py ..` does this help ?

Comment: No, still the same warnings.

Comment: Problem is that these warnings are coming from underlying C++ code and Python can't really supress them directly. Let's see if someone else has an answer for this.

Answer (score 0):

I had run my program all day the next day it said:
[W NNPACK.cpp:79] Could not initialize NNPACK! Reason: Unsupported hardware.
when I added:
os.environ["CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES"]=""
it started working again

Answer (score -1):

Just use these 2 lines of code

```
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings('ignore')
```

Comment: This did not work for me. I guess it is not a python warning but one from c++ or cython, therefore it cant be caught. (like @ayandas mentioned above)

Did it work for you?